# How to create image contains a text for UITabBarItem

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I am trying to put an image that contains a text on UITabBarItem.

I went to our Graphics designer and asked him to create an image for me that contains a text "Summary".

He actually did. ( a png image).. but when I put inside the app, I saw a horrible look..

The Image:
[image]

How it look in the app:
[image]

Comment: You really should NOT put text on your `UITabBarButton`s, that's what the label is for.

Comment: Okey, good point. Put what if you don't have an icon that do represent the meaning of the tab button from the perspective of the customer? And at the same time the label is so small to put your text on it and let a big space freed over him?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an image for a tab bar or toolbar item, you or your designer must work in the image's alpha channel. The colors in the image don't matter at all, the OS only is interested in the alpha channel. In your case, the background of your image should be fully transparent instead of black.

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely possible for you to use custom colors and images instead of the ones provided to you by Apple's own UITabBarController. I used the [code explained in this (really thorough) tutorial](http://www.rumex.it/2010/07/how-to-customise-the-tab-bar-uitabbar-in-an-iphone-application-part-1-of-2/) - works great.